# How to get the folder with the latest yymm in a Directory?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way using python 3.x to get the latest folder with yymm in the name?
Lets say there are folders name like abc1708, abc1707, xyz1709 within a particular Directory.
How to select 1709 from xyz1709 since this is the latest among the three folders?

Any code will be much appreciated...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by _"How to select 1709 from xyz1709..."_?

Comment: @AGNGazer I need to loop through a particular dir and get the folder name which contains latest yymm.

Comment: Finally I have formulated the final answer for my question. :)

folders=(next(os.walk('C:\\Python34\\PyScript'))[1])
folderName=(max(folders, key=lambda x: int(x[-4:])))
result = re.sub(r'[a-z]+', '', folderName)
print (result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dirnames = ['abc1708', 'abc1707', 'xyz1709']
max(dirnames, key=lambda x: int(x[-4:]))
```

If your directory name list contains names that do not end in 4 digits, then you will need to weed out all these names before you can run the above code:

```
dirnames = ['a', 'abc1708', 'abc1707', 'xyz1709', 'nonumbers']

def check_dir_name(f):
    try:
        digits = f[-4:]
        if len(digits) != 4:
            return False
        int(f[-4:])
    except:
        return False
    return True

# first filter out bad directory names:
good_dirnames = [x for x in dirnames if check_dir_name(x)]

# now run the code on "good names" only:
max(good_dirnames, key=lambda x: int(x[-4:]))
```

Comment: I tried your logic, but if there is other folder present other than   containing numbers, its throwing errors.
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lder'**

It is giving the complete folder name name instead of last 4 digit of folder name.
**It is not giving the last four digit only of the folder, but the complete folder name with the latest yymm**

Comment: @King My answer was to your question as it was formulated. Next time try to be more precise when formulating your questions.

Comment: agreed.
anyways Thank you for the answer. :)